# Determine whether a random variable is a stopping time

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Let $\{W_t^0, W_t^1 : t \geq 0\}$ be a 2-dimensional Brownian motion issued from zero. For every $r \in (-1,1)$, we define the stochastic process
$$W_t^r = rW_t^1 + \sqrt{1-r^2}W_t^0, \quad t \geq 0, r \in ]-1, 1[.$$
$\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(W_u^0, W_u^1 : u \leq t) \vee \mathcal{N}$, where $\mathcal{N}$ is the $\mathbb{P}$-null set of $\mathcal{F}$. I have to determine which of the following random variables are stopping times for every $r \in ]-1,1[$.

> $A = inf \{t \geq 0 : W_t^1 + W_t^r  = 5 \}$,
>
> $B = inf\{t \geq 2 : W_t^1  =  W_t^r\}$,
>
> $C = sup\{t \leq 1 :  W_t^1 <  W_t^r\}.$

I know that I should check whether $\{T \leq t \} \in \mathcal{F}_t$, but I don´t know how. Does anyone has an idea ?

Thanks for your help.